# Problems setting up binary function to use transform

Tags: c++

I have a vector of doubles, that I want to transform by multiplying by a double.  I have it in mind to use std::transform, but I am having trouble working it out.  How would I setup up a function to use my "factor" below to transform my init vector to my results vector?

Here is a representation of my code:

```
double a, b, factor;
std::vector<double> init;
std::vector<double> result;



// Code that initializes a, b, and 
// fills in InitVec with timeseries (type double) data

factor = a/b;
result.resize(init.size())
std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), result.begin(), /*function that multiplies init by factor*/)
```

is it as simple as:

```
std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), result.begin(), *factor)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using c++03 or c++11 or above? IE do you have lambdas available or not?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 / 2013.  I think lambdas are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three different ways you can do this, including:

- custom functor class
- lamba instance
- bound binary functor

See below for all three:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct mult_by
{
    double val;
    mult_by(double v) : val(v) {}
    double operator()(double arg) { return arg * val; };
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    double a = 1, b = 2, factor = a/b;

    std::vector<double> init;
    std::vector<double> result;

    init.emplace_back(1.0);
    init.emplace_back(2.0);

    // using a functor
    std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), std::back_inserter(result), mult_by(factor));

    // using a lambda
    std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
                   [factor](double d){ return d * factor; });

    // binding to a standard binary-op (std::multiplies)
    std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
                   std::bind(std::multiplies<double>(), _1, factor));

    // should report three pairs of 0.5 and 1
    for (auto x : result)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Which you choose depends on preference or compiler limitations. Personally I would find the latter distasteful, but presented it as an option just because it is possible. I purposely left out `std::for_each` and outright hand-looped implementations, as those don't appear to be what you're looking for.

Best of luck.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by hand-loop - but I would assume it would be the simple looping through of the vectors I know, and am trying to avoid.  I would really appreciate and example of for_each applied to this.  I am also curious as to whether or not a Range-based for loop could work - something like this:  for(double val : init) {result[val] = val * factor;}

Comment: @traggatmot range based for, `for (auto x : init) result.push_back(x * factor);` would also work if you simply removed the `result.resize()` from your code. Note I used i in *none* of the examples I gave. And yes, I consider that a hand-rolled-loop, thus its omission.

Comment: You left out the hand-rolled loops because....?  These options are so much faster and cleaner?  Which (correct or not) is what my intuition is telling me and why I have been trying to avoid them....

Comment: you may have answered 'above' my question, but in teaching me the correct syntax of several methods I was struggling to teach myself, while giving other constructive info, you certainly started answering those future questions sitting 'above' this one.  Which is great.

Comment: @traggatmot Glad it helped. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function which gets a `double` and returns a new `double`.
And you need to get factor in this function too.
Easy with a lambda expression:

```
std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), result.begin(),  
    [factor](double val) -> double { return val*factor; }
);
```

To understand it better, it is a short version for the following code, except `factor` can be used in the function even if it is just a local variable where `transform` is called:

```
double modify(double val)
{
    return val*factor;
}
...
std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), result.begin(), modify);
```

Ie. a lambda expression is a unnamed function written inline as part of other stuff, and it can "capture" local variables from it´s caller context too.